# Rails 4.2: route not matched if url has %2f character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, escaping

Seems that when there is a slash character into one of the url or path parameters even if it has been correctly escaped, Rails is not able to find the route...

The scenario is this:

I've this routing:

```
get 'request_work_sheet/:item_code/:document_type/:workstation' => 'work_sheets#request_work_sheet'
```

I try to create this link:

```
link_to "Document", request_work_sheet_path("CP/121", "master", "WS1")
```

rails correctly generates this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/request_work_sheet/CP%2F121/master/WS1
```

The url seems right escaped but as soon as I navigate the link the route was not found:

```
No route matches [GET] "/request_work_sheet/CP/121/master/WS1"
```

If the link has not the slash character the route was found...

Any idea ? (many thanks in advance...)

Answer (score 0):

It thinks that `item_code=CP`, `document_type=121`, `workstation=master`, then you have an extra `/WS`, which doesn't map to any route. You can't have / in any param value if you this to work.

Comment: I have a third party application that calls my Rails app and into the database the item codes have the slash character es. XX/YYY, the third party application correctly escapes the slash into %2f but can't finds the route... What you're saying is that I cannot have a route that accepts a slash escaped parameter ?

Comment: Hmm, try this: `get 'request_work_sheet/:item_code/:document_type/:workstation' => 'work_sheets#request_work_sheet', constraints: {item_code: /\w{1,2}\/\d{1,3}/}`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and found that I had to set the "AllowEncodedSlashes On" setting in my apache2.conf file.  Before I did this, apache would block the URL and return a 404 (NOT FOUND).  It never got to my rails routes.  Now everything is passed through as expected.